# Custom labeling with same angle as rectangular object and specific position using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling, cartography

Can the following be done in QGIS? It should be formula based without manual formatting as performed by my predecessor to get the following output.

[image]

So

1. Grave_No on right parallel to the y axis of the grave.
2. Name on top center parallel to the x axis of the grave.
3. Date of Death on bottom center parallel to the x axis of the grave.

I expect that we will need to copy the layer three times to apply custom labels for each of these situations [image]

**In MI**
-I can't autorotate the labels and place them on the left/make sure the angle is the same as the grave. I know it can be done manually per label but this is far to much work.

**In QGIS**
- I can rotate the label but can't get them to always be on the left. I tried 
[image]

and

[image]

I also need to make sure all three labels are shown.

**In ArcMap**
- In maplex, it seems as if we can only rotate point labels but I have a polygon shape. We can't use centroids as it will go out of the grave site.

**So QGIS** seems to get the closest...

[image]

**Note** 1. The name sometimes does not show but the Date of Death does, in other cases this is reversed. Both should be shown. 2. Some will have 2 or more people in the grave so the data will be there twice - so grave no will be E-062a and E-062b for example with 2 names and dates of death as well.

So can I do all the above in QGIS?

Comment: By asking how to do this using QGIS, MapInfo and/or ArcGIS for Desktop you are effectively asking three questions when the [Tour] specifies one question per question.  This make it too broad for focussed Q&A.  I recommend that you just ask about the product you are most likely to use here.  If it cannot do it, then you can always ask about another or both others in separate questions.

Comment: @PolyGeo thanks. I have edited the question to be QGIS for now.

Comment: @PolyGeo I've now amended this to try to find an ArcMap solution as there were no replies for QGIS and I just need it to work in one platform.

Comment: Which bit from "all of the above" are you stuck on when trying to do it in ArcMap?

Comment: Getting the grave no rotated 90 degrees as it is a polygon dataset and the labels to be at same angle as grave.

Comment: Definitely achievable in QGIS. There are some simple ways or harder, depending on what your data are like. Are all the polygons sharing same orientation? Are they all rectangles with 4 corner nodes?