# Custom labels - aligned to rectangular objects, in a specific position and with multiple attributes using Mapinfo?

Tags: labeling, cartography, mapinfo

Can the following be done in Mapinfo? It should be formula based without manual formatting as performed by my predecessor to get the following output.

[image]

So

1. Grave_No on right parallel to the y axis of the grave.
2. Name on top center parallel to the x axis of the grave.
3. Date of Death on bottom center parallel to the x axis of the grave.

I expect that we will need to copy the layer three times to apply custom labels for each of these situations enter image description here

In MI -I can't find a way to autorotate the labels and place them on the left/make sure the angle is the same as the grave. I know it can be done manually per label but this is far to much work.

Note 1. The name sometimes does not show but the Date of Death does, in other cases this is reversed. Both should be shown.
Note 2. Some will have 2 or more people in the grave so the data will be there twice - so grave no will be E-062a and E-062b for example with 2 names and dates of death as well.

Details of what I tried in QGIS and ArcMap are in the following question [Custom labeling with same angle as rectangular object and specific position using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/184952/custom-labeling-with-same-angle-as-rectangular-object-and-specific-position-usin) ... but an MI solution will be best.

So can I do all the above in Mapinfo?