# Custom rotated polygon labels in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, cartography

Can the following be done in ArcMap? It should be formula based without manual formatting as performed by my predecessor (in MapInfo using a lot of manual steps) to get the following output.

[image]

So

1. Grave_No on right parallel to the y axis of the grave.
2. Name on top center parallel to the x axis of the grave.
3. Date of Death on bottom center parallel to the x axis of the grave.

I expect that we will need to copy the layer three times to apply custom labels for each of these situations [image]

**In MI**
-I can't autorotate the labels and place them on the left/make sure the angle is the same as the grave. I know it can be done manually per label but this is far to much work.

**In QGIS**
- See [Custom labeling with same angle as rectangular object and specific position using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/184952/custom-labeling-with-same-angle-as-rectangular-object-and-specific-position-usin)

**In ArcMap**
- In maplex, it seems as if we can only rotate point labels but I have a polygon shape. We can't use centroids as it will go out of the grave site. [image]

**So QGIS** seems to get the closest...and while I am happy to have a QGIS solution I have asked a new question (as there were no responses) to just have an ArcMap solution.

[image]

**Note** 1. The name sometimes does not show but the Date of Death does, in other cases this is reversed. Both should be shown. 2. Some will have 2 or more people in the grave so the data will be there twice - so grave no will be E-062a and E-062b for example with 2 names and dates of death as well.

So can I do all the above in ArcMap? the example shows how far I could get it.

Comment: In ArcGIS you can specify Always Straight in Placement. Thus the best way forward I think is split of polygon into 3 items using script.

Comment: Have a look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/159631/splitting-all-polygon-features-in-a-shapefile-into-smaller-equal-width-polygons with very little tweak you'll be able to split your originals into 2 horizontal first and say 5(?) verticals in a second go

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at annotations (not grapic elements). When you export your labels to a file-geodatabase the label options becoming columns in the attribut-table of the annotation. There you can calculate the angle field to have your rotations/colors/offsets based on some formula.

[image]

When you create your labels in the first place as label-classes for your different offsets/colors/rotations you don´t have to create several layers. The classes will be afterwards in the attribute table and can be used for a conditional calculation of the roatations. Something like "If attribut=5 and labelclass=2 return rotation = 90". The calculated values will automaticly be applied to the annotations.

[image]